# TextField is gaining focus after navigating to another screen

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

In my project I've wrapped the whole `MaterialApp` in a `GestureDetector` which is supposed to dismiss keyboard when user tapped the screen, using this piece of code

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus()
```

After testing multiple scenarios it wasn't working so I decided to do it the wrong way

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode())
```

But now I'm experiencing another issue. Here is my code for a simple screen which is instantiated by `MaterialApp`'s `routes` builder.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestScreenState createState() => _TestScreenState();
}

class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(),
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TestScreen())),
              child: Text('Test'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The steps to reproduce error is: 1-Start editing `TextField`. 2-Unfocus `TextField` by tapping somewhere on screen. 3-Tap on button to navigate to another screen. This is the result:

[image]

This behavior is not happening when I'm trying to unfocus `TextField` by pressing keyboard's done button. According to the source code when done button is pressed, `TextField` is calling `clearComposing` on `TextEditingController`. I even tried that but got no luck. How can I fix it? Does anyone else have better solution to handle dismissing keyboard in Flutter?

Also here is my `flutter doctor` result:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: bro give it try https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_avoider

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. This library is changing scrolling behavior @ParthPitroda

Comment: why you are not doing FocusScope.of(context).unfocus() inside onPressed ?

Comment: It's not working and `TextField` is still in focus @jitsm555

Comment: do you want to first close the keyboard then want to navigate?  Not clear with your question

Comment: I described the procedure to reproduce the issue. After tapping on screen `TextField` focus is removing but after trying to navigate to other screen it's gaining focus again @jitsm555

Comment: I am assuming on your next screen you don't have TextField? is my assumption right?

Comment: Yes but in the original app. In this sample next screen has `TextField` too. So It's happening in both situation @jitsm555

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219398/discussion-between-jitsm555-and-amir-p).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally this line of code solved my issue:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.focusManager.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
```

I'm not aware of side effects of it but It's working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Set a focusNode to the text field and, after push the new route, focus next node and unfocus current, like:

```
// push your new route here

myNode.nextFocus();
myNode.unfocus();
// myNode needs to be the last text field
```

When you press back, from the new route, the focus will not reappear automatically anymore.

Worked for me.